# jQuery UI Datepicker - onSelect get the selected date +3 days

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I try to create a date range by using the jQuery UI datepicker, using two text fields. The first text field "start_date" will set the start date and the second text field "end_date" will set the end date.

The code I have till now is this:

```
$('#start_date').live(
    'focus',
    function()
    {
        $('#end_date').datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
                minDate: new Date(),
                maxDate: new Date(2012, 9, 15),
                stepMonths: 2,
                numberOfMonths: 2
            }
        );

        $(this).datepicker(
            {
                dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
                minDate: new Date(),
                maxDate: new Date(2012, 9, 15),
                stepMonths: 2,
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst)
                {
                    var instance = $( this ).data("datepicker");

                    var date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, dateText, instance.settings);

                    $('#end_date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateText);
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

**NOTE** : I use the live and the focus event because all my page content is loaded with AJAX call. Maybe that is correct or wrong, but this is not what I like to ask here ;)

The above code is correct for me and work fine, but what I like to do, is to **set** the value of the 'end_date' element to selected one +3 days.

Until now, when I choose a date at the "start_date" element the "end_date" element change to the same date as the "start_date", and this is what I like to change. The "end_date" to be +3 days from the "start_date" element adter the selection.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To set end_date for +1 day

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    $('#start_date').datepicker('option','minDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
    var toDate = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay);//Date one month after selected date
    var oneDay = new Date(toDate.getTime()+86400000);
    document.getElementById('end_date').value =$.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', oneDay);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hiya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/96Lbf/

This demo will set `to` text box with `+3 days` taking `from date selection into account.

**jquery code**

```
   $(function() {
        $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                if(this.id == 'from'){
                  var dateMin = $('#from').datepicker("getDate");
                  var rMin = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() + 1); 
                  var rMax = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() + 3); 
                  //$('#to').datepicker("option","minDate",rMin);
                  //$('#to').datepicker("option","maxDate",rMax);  
$('#to').val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm-dd-yy', new Date(rMax)));                    
                }

            }
        });
    });
```

**Html**

```
<div class="demo"> 

<label for="from">From</label> 
<input type="text" id="from" name="from"/> 
<label for="to">to</label> 
<input type="text" id="to" name="to"/> 

</div>​
```

Answer (score 1):

> If month = 4, I want to see car1 picture. If month = 5, i want to see car3 picture. How can I do it?

```
//..............
onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
  if(this.id == 'from'){
    var dateMin = $('#from').datepicker("getDate");
    var rMin = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() + 0);
    alert (rMin.getMonth());
    if(rMin.getMonth() == 4){ 
      var image1=new Image();
      image1.src="car1.jpg"
      if(rMin.getMonth() ==5){
        var image2=new Image()
        image2.src="car3.jpg";
      }                           
    }
  }
}
```

```
    <label for="from">From</label> 
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from"/> 

    <label for="pics">pics</label> 
    <input type="image"
           src="car1.jpg"
           id="pics"
           name="pics"
           alt="Submit"
           width="48" height="48">

...............
```