# how to copy a selected date between textboxes in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a StartDate and EndDate in an ASP.NET using c# webpage. When user fills in start date - I want this to be copied to enddate until user changes the end date. How can we possibly do that. The code I have  as as below

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="m_eventform" runat="server" Visible="true">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#<%= m_eventDate.ClientID %>').datepick({ dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' });
        $('#<%= m_eventEndDate.ClientID %>').datepick({ dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' });
    });
</script>
<form id="eventForm" runat="server">

<div class="formrow">
    <label>
      Start Date</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="m_eventDate" runat="server" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="m_eventDateRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="m_eventDate"
        ErrorMessage="Please enter a start date" Display="Dynamic" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="m_eventDateReg" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^\d{4}[\-]?((((0[13578])|(1[02]))[\-]?(([0-2][0-9])|(3[01])))|(((0[469])|(11))[\-]?(([0-2][0-9])|(30)))|(02[\-]?[0-2][0-9]))$"
        ControlToValidate="m_eventDate" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter the date in YYYY-MM-DD format" />
</div>

  <div class="formrow">
    <label>
        End Date</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="m_eventEndDate" runat="server" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="m_eventEndDateRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="m_eventEndDate"
        ErrorMessage="Please enter an end date" Display="Dynamic" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ValidationExpression="^\d{4}[\-]?((((0[13578])|(1[02]))[\-]?(([0-2][0-9])|(3[01])))|(((0[469])|(11))[\-]?(([0-2][0-9])|(30)))|(02[\-]?[0-2][0-9]))$"
        ControlToValidate="m_eventEndDate" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter the date in YYYY-MM-DD format" />
</div>


</form>
```

Comment: I would look at using javascript's blur event to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Date picker has an onselect function that could be used :
    
`$('#<%= m_eventDate.ClientID %>').datepick(
          { dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
           onSelect : function(dateText,inst){
               if(!endDateSelected){
                 $('#<%= m_eventEndDate.ClientID %>').val(dateText);
               } 
           }
           });`

`$('#<%= m_eventEndDate.ClientID %>').datepick(
          { dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
           onSelect : function(dateText,inst){
            endDateSelected = true;
          } 
           });`

This will keep you from having to write extra C# code.  Adding the onSelect function to the enddate selector will prevent the end date from continually being updated every time the user changes the start date.

You can also checkout this post for a similar situation: 
[jQuery UI Datepicker - onSelect get the selected date +3 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530134/jquery-ui-datepicker-onselect-get-the-selected-date-3-days)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your markup like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="m_eventDate" runat="server" onblur="copyDate();" />
```

and then add this JavaScript:

```
function copyDate() {
    $('#<%= m_eventEndDate.ClientID %>').val($('#<%= m_eventDate.ClientID %>').val);
}
```

#### Recommendation

I would recommend, if you're using .NET 4.0, to leverage the new `ClientIDMode` property for the text boxes. You could set it like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="m_eventDate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

and then in JavaScript you'll be able to reference them like this instead:

```
$('#m_eventDate') ...
```

because their `id` won't be changed server-side by the naming container.