# jquery ui selecting data range using datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using the jquery datepicker.
So i am enabling the users to select a checkin date. 
From general knowledge, you can't select a check out date earlier than the check in date.
I have been trying to set the check out date outmatically as soon as the user selects the checkout date and make sure it is at least a day after.
That is, if the user selects the date to be 07/23/2014 then the checkout field should be automatically set to 07/24/2014 before the user changes.

The code below does not seem to do that.. please help

```
$('#checkindate').datepicker(
{
    showButtonPanel: true,
    minDate:0,
     onClose: function(selectedDate)
    {
        $( "#checkoutdate" ).datepicker("option","minDate",selectedDate);
        alert(selectedDate+"1D");
    }   
});
```

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530134/jquery-ui-datepicker-onselect-get-the-selected-date-3-days

Answer (score 0):

In the following sample I got 2 datetime selectors like you, I edited with the name of your items:

```
var startDateTextBox = $('#checkindate');
var endDateTextBox = $('#checkoutdate');

// Start-End Date pickers
startDateTextBox.datepicker({
    // Update other date from selection
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        var testStartDate = startDateTextBox.datepicker('getDate');
        if (endDateTextBox.val()) {
            var testEndDate = endDateTextBox.datepicker('getDate');
            if (testStartDate > testEndDate)
                endDateTextBox.datepicker('setDate', testStartDate);
        }
        else {
            endDateTextBox.datepicker('setDate', testStartDate);
        }
    },
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        endDateTextBox.datepicker('option', 'minDate', startDateTextBox.datepicker('getDate'));
    }
});

endDateTextBox.datepicker({
    // Update other date from selection
    onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
        var testStartDate = startDateTextBox.datepicker('getDate');
        if (startDateTextBox.val()) {
            var testEndDate = endDateTextBox.datepicker('getDate');
            if (testStartDate > testEndDate)
                startDateTextBox.datepicker('setDate', testEndDate);
        }
        else {
            startDateTextBox.datepicker('setDate', testStartDate);
        }
    },
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        startDateTextBox.datepicker('option', 'maxDate', endDateTextBox.datepicker('getDate'));
    }
});
```